# Unable to launch the ios app in proxy setting for record and running perf test in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record and run an IOS mobile app in jmeter, but the app is not running in proxy setting. application is not launching, then how will I record and run performance test in jmeter.

Steps what i followed:

added https test script recorder  to workbench, and then added recording controller to the thread group.
target controller in https  test script recorder is set to Test plan> thread group> record controller.

note the app is http not https, still then emailed the .crt file and installed in the device.

Comment: it just recorded the homepage not navigating to other pages links.

Comment: have you actually tried to record after setting the proxy? the application will not work or launch if you have not clicked on Start recording option in JMeter.

Comment: Try using recorder from "Templates" and configure Proxy settings